# Defining Files to a java program at runtime

Tags: java

Hello all java newbie here...
I'm writing a java program that has to read from an external text file, (inquiries) and 
then write out the responses to the inquiries to another external text file.

Now the program will not know the path name of the files until run time when the path name 
for both the input and output files will be passed via the arguments parameter. 
The path name will be the same for both files, the actual file names I have defined in two
string variables..e.g.

```
final static string RqstFname = "RqstFile.txt" 
final static string RespFname = "RespFile.txt"
```

Now all the examples of File constructor use always have a **hardcoded** `path\file_name string`. 
can I pass a string variable to the `File Contructor` ??

Thanks very much

Comment: Just wondering... but... did you try it to see what happened?

Comment: [Javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) say ... of course you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static final String REQUEST_FILENAME = "RqstFile.txt";
private static final String RESPONSE_FILENAME = "RespFile.txt";

private File requestFile = null;
private File responseFile = null; 

void prepareFiles(String configuredPath)
{
    requestFile = new File(configuredPath, REQUEST_FILENAME);
    responseFile = new File(configuredPath, RESPONSE_FILENAME);
}

public File getRequestFile() { return requestFile; }
public File getResponseFile() { return responseFile; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can pass a path string to the [`File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) constructor:

```
public void myMethod(String myString) {
    File myFile = new File(myString);
}
```